# Are there any downsides to fishing to depletion?

Tags: dredge

While fishing in Dredge, it's possible (and in fact, very easy) to fish until a spot is completely depleted. Is there any reason *not* to do this, aside from running out of space in my boat? Will the cthonic horrors of the depths be offended if I kidnap all their smaller brethren?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there doesn't seem to be any downside. I do this regularly and nothing bad has happened.

In fact there is a trophy associated with this:

> Careless Harvesting - deplete 25 sites